# How do I test a CPU?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, hp-pavilion

I've been trying to repair a friends computer.  It's been a trial and error process.  Starting with the least expensive fixes.

The original problem is that the system would not power up. The PSU fan would sometimes spin, but no other signs of life on the computer.  None of the fans connected to the motherboard would spin.  No sign of the hard drive spinning up.

Replaced PSU.  Also bought a PSU tester.  Both units were working.

Still nothing was working.

Replaced motherboard.  All of the attachments are now working.  However, there is no image on the computer monitor.

Reset BIOS.  Same result.

Attached a video card.  Still no image.

I'm beginning to suspect that whatever took out the motherboard also took out the CPU.

Is there a cost effective way of testing a CPU?

Details:

- AAHD2-HY (Holly) Motherboard
- AMD E2 3200 Processor

[HP Pavilion p6-2003w Desktop PC Product Specifications](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03052733&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5156903#N99)

Comment: Could you try removing all memory DIMM's and booting up to see if you get a display (even through it wont boot).. Also do you have a PC speaker plugged in to the motherboard as you should expect 'beeps' to advise on what component is failing upon power up...

Comment: If you have tried two motherboards and the system will still not POST, then its the CPU, POST is how you determine the CPU is working.

Answer (score 3):

The most cost effective way to test a CPU is to have another known-good MB you can place it into with known-good memory and peripherals.

Computer shops should be able to test this for you quite easily, some of the better ones might even allow you to do it under their oversight.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question title:**

There is no real way to test a CPU, either it works or not.

If - as in this case - the computer does not turn on after testing all other components then your CPU is gone, no need to test it.

Get a new one and make sure it uses the same socket as your motherboard.

Good luck

**Now to your second question:** ***Is there a cost effective way of testing a CPU?***

See music2myear's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/815070/181734).